# How to chromecast my embedded youtube videos?

Tags: html, youtube, embed, chromecast

I have a website that has embedded videos from youtube on it.

Is there any way to enable chromecasting on them? I've seen several news articles saying there is chromecast support for embedded youtube videos, but I can't find any documentation on it.

Do I add any parameters to the video url?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't have to add anything to a youtube video to be compatible with the chromecast, just use the youtube's provided link and it should work.

https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/2995235?hl=en-CA

"Casting from YouTube is supported from the YouTube app, YouTube.com, and most embedded YouTube videos."

Have a nice day!